# Polling TCP/IP in UWP background

Tags: uwp, network-programming, windows-10-universal, tcpclient

I need to communicate from a Windows 10 univeral application with some peripheral devices connected via TCP/IP. Specifically, these are MODBUS devices and I need to constantly poll the devices (multiple times per second) in order to read status values and act upon them accordingly. The application will have multiple forms and each of those forms will be capable of receiving data based upon the values read from the peripherals.

My current (Win32) implementation runs a couple of background threads that simply send the read command, read the result and then process the results as required by raising events that the various forms can subscribe to and I believe that this is the approach that I should also be taking within UWP.

Is there a better way when using UWP? Will this work if the application is moved into the background and/or can I prevent suspension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed implementation sounds like the best approach for an application that needs to poll these devices. Do the polling off the UI thread and marshall the events for your pages to collect the processed data from.

For running while minimized: If you only need to collect this information while the foreground app is running, then Extended Execution may be the option for you. When you minimize the app it will automatically move to the suspended state unless you request some form of lifetime extension. You can request the [Unspecified Extended Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution), which has limits when on battery power than can be removed based on user settings. This will enable the app to run when minimized, but not when closed.